# How to view the output of PCA in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I have a PCA `results = PCA(myData)`,I am using numpy to implement it. How can I get or where can I see the output?

Comment: Is this using sklearn? What do you *want* to see? eigenvectors/eigenvalues? Transformed data?

Comment: @bogatron I want to see the output in Graph format

Comment: My short answer is to use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) but there are plenty of [python plotting packages](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting).